# Getting response from axios function

Tags: javascript, typescript, vuejs3

When calling the lookUpItem function from ItemSearch.vue I get undefined.

ItemSearch.vue

```
   <script setup lang="ts">
      import { lookUpItem } from '../systemApi'

      async function getItemDetails() {
         const response = await lookUpItem(mNumber, location)      
}
   </script>
```

systemAPI.ts

```
export async function lookUpItem(mNumber: number, location: number) {
   getHash().then((hash) => {
      axios.get(url)
      .then((response) => {
         // console.log(response) <- outputs the correct data to console.
         return response
}
```

Comment: The method `lookUpItem` does not return a value to the caller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

For better reading (and understanding)

```
export async function lookUpItem(mNumber: number, location: number) {
  try{
     const hash = await getHash();
     const response = await axios.get(url);
     return response;
  }catch(err){
    throw err;
  }
}
```

Comment: I updated it as you suggested. With the getItemDetails function I changed it to await lookUpItem(mNumber, location).then(response => response).then(data => console.log(data)) and I get what I'm looking for. Thank you.